Dative usage for relations (e.g., family, hierarchy, emotional etc.) and quality of relations
I‘ve read the following sentence:

Я не кровный родственник этой семье, но, наверное, именно поэтому я могу смотреть на всё со стороны.

Here, семья stands in the dative, instead of the genitive. Is this usage of the dative case dated/archaic or regular modern usage?
Generalising from this, can I use the dative to describe relations or qualities of relations between objects and/or persons? Like, e.g.,

(Relation) Он был своему народу благостным королём.
(Quality of relation) Король был своему народу благостным.



Я не кровный родственник этой семье, но, наверное, именно поэтому я могу смотреть на всё со стороны.

This is so called дательный обладания "possessive dative".
It is in regular modern usage and expresses intrinsic, usually personal, relationships (kinship, affection, hierarchy, and similar): он мне как брат; я ему не враг; слуга царю, отец солдатам; кум королю etc.

Generalising from this, can I use the dative to describe relations or qualities of relations between objects and/or persons?

Yes, you can, when the object in the dative is used as a predicate.
I.e.

Он был своему народу благостным королём.

is ok, but

Король был своему народу благостным.

is not.

Ah great. What you wrote is also consistent, with what I just found, and might be an interesting read for those with similar questions as mine: Levine, J. S. (1984). On the Dative of Possession in Contemporary Russian. The Slavic and East European Journal, 28(4), 493–501. https://doi.org/10.2307/307636

@Truubehüeter Thank you for accepting the answer. Going forward, can you please consider waiting a couple of days before accepting? There's always a chance anyone can give another answer with more perspective, but people are less inclined to participate in questions that already have an accepted answer. Thank you!


Я не кровный родственник этой семье...

This sounds like good modern-day literary Russian. Nothing archaic or dated about this sentence.

(Relation) Он был своему народу благостным королём.

Same here, except that благостный is a bit dated and high-style.

(Quality of relation) Король был своему народу благостным.

This doesn't sound right.
Yes, you can use dative to express relations:

Я тебе не отец - I'm not your father (which is different from "Я не твой отец", more like "I'm not a father to you").

